# Getting number of unique paths traversed while traversing using Neo4j traversal API

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-traversal-api

I have created following basic graph:

```
CREATE (:NodeType1 {prop1:'value1'})-[:RelType1 {prop2:'value2'}]->(:NodeType2 {prop3:'value3'})-[:RelType2 {prop4:'value4'}]->(:NodeType3 {prop5:'value5'})-[:RelType3 {prop6:'value6'}]->(:NodeType4 {prop7:'value7'})

CREATE (:NodeType1 {prop1:'value8'})-[:RelType1 {prop2:'value9'}]->(:NodeType2 {prop3:'value10'})-[:RelType2 {prop4:'value11'}]->(:NodeType3 {prop5:'value12'})-[:RelType3 {prop6:'value13'}]->(:NodeType4 {prop7:'value14'})

MATCH path=(n:NodeType1 {prop1:'value1'})-[*]->(m:NodeType4 {prop7:'value7'})
CREATE (n)-[:RelType1 {prop2:'value15'}]->(:NodeType2 {prop3:'value16'})-[:RelType2 {prop4:'value17'}]->(:NodeType3 {prop5:'value18'})-[:RelType3 {prop6:'value19'}]->(m)
```

The graph looks like this:

[image]

When I run following cypher:

```
MATCH path=(a:NodeType1 {prop1:"value1"})-[:RelType1]->(b)-[:RelType2]->(c)-[:RelType3]->(d)
RETURN count(nodes(path))
```

I get `2` as the output. It seems that `nodes()` doesnt actually return the number nodes in the path but simply the number of rows in the returned result, since if I return the `path`:

```
MATCH path=(a:NodeType1 {prop1:"value1"})-[:RelType1]->(b)-[:RelType2]->(c)-[:RelType3]->(d)
RETURN path
```

I get two rows in the returned result:

[image]

Now I am guessing how can I get the same output when doing traversal using Neo4J traversal API. I get number of unique nodes in the cypher as follows:

```
MATCH path=(a:NodeType1 {prop1:"value1"})-[:RelType1]->(b)-[:RelType2]->(c)-[:RelType3]->(d)
RETURN size(collect(distinct a))+size(collect(distinct b))+size(collect(distinct c))+size(collect(distinct d))
```

Above query correctly returns `6`.

Same can be done in the traversal API by having static counter inside path expander which is incremented each time `expand()` is called. (Is there any better approach for this?)

```
public class MyPathExpander implements PathExpander{
    static int nodeCount = 0;

    @Override
    public Iterable expand(Path path, BranchState state) {
        Node lastNode = path.endNode();

        nodeCount++;  //**increment the count of nodes visited

        if(lastNode.hasLabel(MyLabels.NodeType1))
            return lastNode.getRelationships(MyRelations.RelType1, Direction.OUTGOING);
        else if (lastNode.hasRelationship(MyRelations.RelType1, Direction.INCOMING))
            return lastNode.getRelationships(MyRelations.RelType2, Direction.OUTGOING);
        else if (lastNode.hasRelationship(MyRelations.RelType2, Direction.INCOMING))
            return lastNode.getRelationships(MyRelations.RelType3, Direction.OUTGOING);
        else if (lastNode.hasRelationship(MyRelations.RelType3, Direction.INCOMING))
            return null;
        return null;
    }
}
```

However I am not able to think of way which will tell me number of unique paths followed during traversal while using Traversal API (equivalent to above `RETURN count(nodes(path))`). How can I do this? Is it not possible with traversal API?

PS: By unique path I mean unique permutations of order of nodes visited while traversing. For example, all `a-b-c`, `a-c-b` and `a-b-c-d` are unique.

Comment: `nodes(path)` return array of nodes from path, not count of nodes...

Answer (score 0):

This query not return count of unique path, but count of all paths return by query:

```
MATCH path=(a:NodeType1 {prop1:"value1"})-[:RelType1]->(b)
           -[:RelType2]->(c)-[:RelType3]->(d)
RETURN count(nodes(path))
```

If you want to count the number of unique nodes in the query, you can do so:

```
MATCH path=(a:NodeType1 {prop1:"value1"})-[:RelType1]->(b)
           -[:RelType2]->(c)-[:RelType3]->(d)
UNWIND nodes(path) AS N
RETURN count(distinct N)
```

One way to count the number of unique paths will be (for each path calculates its unique fingerprint, it will not be difficult to repeat by traversal API):

```
MATCH path=(a:NodeType1 {prop1:"value1"})-[:RelType1]->(b)
           -[:RelType2]->(c)-[:RelType3]->(d)
WITH path, 
     REDUCE(acc="", x in nodes(path) | acc + id(x)) +
     REDUCE(acc="", x in rels(path) | acc + id(x)) as uniID    
RETURN count(distinct uniID)
```

Comment: Will number of paths and number of unique paths returned by cypher ever be different. I feel both will be same always.

Comment: Also its weird that `RETURN nodes(path)` return number of paths, especially when `RETURN path,nodes(path)` correctly returns `path,nodes`. However `RETURN path,count(nodes(path))` return `path,1`, i.e. `1` for all paths. So, I tried to get number of nodes in the path by something like this: `RETURN path,COUNT(UNWIND nodes(path))`. It gives error.I know we can do:`RETURN path,length(path)+1` as number of nodes = 1+number of relationships & `length(path)` return number of relationships. But then can we do it with `COUNT(UNWIND nodes(path))`?so that we can do `COUNT(distinct UNWIND nodes(path))`